# What is Test Bed? How to use it?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing

Is **Test bed** a Tool? Or is it an *Environment* set-up?

How to use Test Bed?

Where to Use Test Bed?

If it's a plugin, how do I configure it with Automated tools?

What is the difference between Test Bed and Test Environment?

Comment: I suggest you start with Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testbed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Let me google that for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of my experience-In simple words-

First of all -Test Bed is not a Tool or not a plugin. It is a platform or we can say it as- method which is used to test a particular module. It is the combination of hardware and software environment on which the tests will be executed.
It includes hardware configuration, operating system settings, software configuration,test terminals, network configuration, the product under test and other support to perform the test.

---

For **example** consider a web-based application:

```
Web Server - IIS/Apache
Database - MS SQL
OS - Windows/ Linux
Browser - IE/FireFox
Java version : version 6
```

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testbed):

> A **test bed** is a platform for conducting rigorous, transparent, and replicable testing of scientific theories, computational tools, and new technologies.

A **test environment** is the required hardware and software technologies needed to conduct testing. A test bed is not a tool. It is a platform.

Answer (score 0):

In a very generic sense a test-bed could be defined as a kind of development environment whereby the implements of code or modules have the freedom of testing their modules without any disturbances from the testing team, in absolute confinement. However a test bed is not only specific to a development team. In the perspective of a test team or a tester, since the test bed is nothing but a platform identified for software / product testing, it is also interchangeably called a test environment. Any test bed or test environment would have to be configured in accordance to meet the identified test goal for the application/ product / software under test. In certain situations a test bed would be the collation of the test environment and the test data it operates with.

Answer (score 0):

Is Test bed a Tool? Or is it an Environment set-up?
Test bed is not tool, its just a environment/platform required for performing software/ product testing. Test bed could be defined as a kind of development environment for development team and a test environment for a test team in software testing company.

How to use Test Bed?

Any test bed / test environment will comprise of the hardware, software, and the networking in order to support the required configuration as per the test requirement to conduct the particular test.

Below are some suggestions on how to effectively prepare the setup for testing:-

Tip 1: Understand the test requirements thoroughly and educate yourself
In order to perform testing for any product, you need to understand all the test requirement required to conduct your test.
This can be achieved by talking to the development team / architects/product specification document in order to build a good product knowledge base. This would not only save sometime in the execution cycle, but will also help a tester allocate his execution time effectively between simple and complex tests.

Tip 2: Checking the connectivity
Another most important checkpoint is to make sure that the resources or assets you intend to use for testing are reachable. In case the system needs to be run integrated with other machines, check their connectivity with each other by using ping or telnet.

Tip 4: Check for the required hardware and software, licenses
Many a times it so happens that testers begin execution on the systems without checking the needed hardware and software that maybe required. As a result of this many a times a tester realizes almost during the testing cycle that certain functionality is available only on a higher level of hardware or software / firmware. At that time the tester will flag a blocker in his test effort which eats up considerable testing time. Hence it is a priceless practice to have a checkpoint to make a note of the hardware and software that is needed priorly.

Tip 5: Browsers and versions
The testing you do has to mirror what an end user will perform. He could be testing on a particular browser on the latest versions of all browsers. Hence it’s mandatory to identify the different kind of browsers that would be used for testing and have them installed in your own local test setup. Secondly, also identify what versions of browsers need to be used for testing. A good practice would be to start with a browser of the lower version, thereby ensuring backward compatibility and then upgrade to the latest version.

Where to Use Test Bed?
Test bed is platform/environment which are nothing other than the  tools/software/hardware/network that are required for conducting testing for a product or developing a software/product.

What is difference between Test Bed and Test Environment?
Both are the same,  environment created by tester are termed as Test Environment.

Answer (score 0):

Test bed is a platform or environment where we can test the application wef. Software, hardware, networking & different kind of operating system. Basically it is used both in product based as well as service based company. Generally Test bed is used for product based company only, but sometimes it is applicable for service based as well. Be remember Test bed is not any tool or any pluggins or any software.

Comment: can you add some links to help make your answer a more authoritative resource?